# Why didn't this hurt Stark as badly as it did to Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*

> Hulk briefly wields all six Infinity Stones in the new gauntlet and screams in pain and is barely able to snap. It's also stated that he was the best fit for the gauntlet.

However

> Stark later wields all 6 and while evidently in pain, is still able to snap with little effort and even says "I am Iron Man". While the snap does kill him, it doesn't seem like wielding them hurt him nearly as badly.

Why is this? Adrenaline, desperation, or something else?

Comment: I think the snap can kill, not holding the gauntlet.

Comment: Who stated he was the best fit for the gauntlet? Are you sure "fit" is the right word?

Answer (score 32):

Smart Hulk took longer and had more pain whilst wielding the Infinity Stones in the Infinity Gauntlet because he was trying to bring Nat back and undo the previous snap by Thanos. Bringing Nat back is, however, impossible and so he was essentially fighting the Stones before he just gave in and reversed the Snap.

> **Smart Hulk:** You know, I tried. When I had the gauntlet, the stones, I really tried to bring her back.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

However, Tony just removed the Thanos, his Children and his armies from 2014 so had less to do.

As we can see the affects of the snap on Smart Hulk were less than they were on Tony who:

> Dies from it

Whereas Smart Hulk merely has his arm hurt.

It’s also worth noting that Smart Hulk has superhuman healing abilities and so has a higher chance of surviving the Stone’s powers as he would be more resilient that Stark who is a normal, albeit highly intelligent, human.

Smart Hulk was "made for this" as his own exposure to gamma radiation, both in the initial accident and later on to combine Hulk and Banner into Smart Hulk, matches that of the Stones' radiation. So it seems he always had a greater chance of surviving the snap than Tony.

> **Smart Hulk:** We don't. But the radiation's mostly gamma. It's like... uh... I was made for this.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Lastly, Tony's armour also takes away some of the energy of the Stones and the Snap off of himself, as you can see the power coursing across it and the damage to it afterwards from the Snap. So whilst he is hurt more than Smart Hulk, he survives longer than he should have done because the suit saved him a bit.

[image: Tony wields the Stones with the power coursing across him]

Comment: I guess that's fair. I thought when Hulk was hurt, it wasn't from what he was trying to do, it was because he had all six stones. It had the same burst of energy that went through Thanos in IW and that was what seemed to hurt Hulk. I might be wrong.

Comment: Dont forget that the Hulk also has superhuman healing abilities (well beyond any human normal) whereas Stark is just an augmented human.

Comment: Also recall that when Thanos used the stones early in Endgame, he was nearly killed by the power necessary for that use.  It does seem that what one does with the stones is related to how much power is necessary to perform that act.  While Hulk's universe-impacting act required far more power that Tony's field-of-battle impact, Hulk is far more resilient than Tony.

Comment: I'm not asking about why Tony died or anything like that, it's stated in the movie. But it seemed to me like just wearing the stones hurt both Thanos and Hulk. Why wasn't Tony hurt from wearing them?

Comment: @Gremer If you're asking why Tony didn't suffer immediate consequences upon inserting the stones, I think it must be that his armor protected him. This is also why Tony doesn't experience the same immediate power surge Thanos and Hulk suffer. But he wasn't completely immune: slivers of light start to course through Tony just after he mounts the stones, and there is evidence of the type of skin damage Quill and other mortals suffer when handling a stone. Had he not snapped, I think there's on-screen evidence to suggest he would soon have been consumed by that power despite the armor.

Comment: @Rob Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to ask. Thank you. I guess the armor idea makes sense, but it seems odd given that the other gauntlets were made specifically for the stones. Maybe he saw what happened and his nanobots were stopping the surge or something.

Comment: @Gremer Another possibility: The moment the stones snap into place (or the gaunlet is put on) is when they release power based on what the user intends to do with them. Although I think the answer that the suit absorbed part of the power makes more sense.

Comment: One of the theories floating around about the various gloves is that you need to "commune" through the soul-  and mind stone to convey your intent before you can snap. Both Thanos and Hulk had fairly complicated requests involving the entire universe whereas Tony's was much more direct and viceral.

Comment: There are way too many "whilst"s in there than can be healthy for a single human being. :)

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Whilst I appreciate your comment, there are only 2 so I think I'll leave them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - 2 is greater than 0!

Comment: So the magnitude of the task might affect the effect of the stones? So if he'd just asked for an egg mayo sandwich he'd just get a headache? Interesting

Comment: @GordonBennett That _appears_ to be the case considering the different effects but it isn't necessarily true. The best example if Thanos who is affected differently on both snaps.

Answer (score 5):

1. It is incorrect that this character wasn't hurt as badly. He had visible damage on the entire side of his body, and later, **literally died.** I believe that is as much as a character can be hurt!
2. The Hulk has regenerative capabilities, so his powers were probably healing while he was trying to not just undo, but try to restore that other thing. Hence he didn't die.

Comment: You may wish to read the comments on the other answer. OP isn’t asking about effects of using the stones, in which case Tony obviously has the worst effect. OP is asking about the affects of simply wearing the gauntlet and how that seems to hurt others more than Tony.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Hulk said in *Endgame* the cosmic energy from the Stones is mostly gamma and Hulk is gamma immune to a certain degree if not completely. However Tony is just a regular human being which is why he suffered greater consequences. Despite the difference in their usage of the Stones Tony died even though he did lesser with the Stones because ultimately he is a regular human. So doing virtually anything with all 6 would have killed him.

Answer (score 0):

This version of Stark's armor was specifically designed to absorb energy. Remember when Thor shoots lightning at him. Stark's armor was able to protect him from enough of the Stones' energy.

Comment: The Stone's energy was a lot stronger and different than Thor's lightning though. Also when he absorbs Thor's lightning the armour specifically reshapes itself to absorb it whereas with the Stones it does not.

Answer (score -2):

Hulk was only hurt as bad as he was because he went from 0 to 6 stones immediately.

Remember, Thanos got every stone 1 at a time and had time to acclimate to each stone's powers.

Also, he was using a gauntlet made by Earth metals created by Tony Stark and as bad ass as it looked, it wasn't a legendary gauntlet created by Eitri the dwarf.

I believe that having the proper gauntlet alone would have helped and Hulk would have been OK.

As far as I can tell tony was just desperate and also he had full Iron Man armour maybe the armour acted as a buffer but who knows.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up?